Flutter app is strangely rendering green on specific devices
I am developing an app for Android and I just released it for testing.
I have around 15 testers on Android. Nobody had any rendering problems, until yesterday when someone installed the app on their Samsung A03s with version 13 of Android.
3 users had very unexpected behaviour, with every text, container and images in green color (see pictures).
I really have no idea what to do. I have'nt been able to find a solution.
Please I would appreciate any help or guidance on resolving this problem.  
I have tried updating flutter to the lastest version and still nothing.

having same issue, have you solved this?

No, not yet. But I'm taking the app apart at the moment. I don't really know if the problem has been solved.

@Solace Owodaha, disable impeller, he does this. Issue will be fixed in flutter 3.25, you can test fix with firebase Test Lab(Samsung Galaxy A12, for example).
